# Wake on wlan should work but doesn't

Tags: networking, wlan, wake-on-lan

[Following these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332960/how-to-check-if-my-device-supports-wake-on-wlan), I found that `phy0` on my desktop should support wake on wlan and turned it on.

```
[root@Arch alex]# iw phy0 wowlan show
WoWLAN is enabled:
 * wake up on magic packet
```

However, when I suspend the system and try to wake it up from a distance, it doesn't work:

```
[alex@Archlaptop tmp]$ wol 44:E5:17:ED:9E:D2r
Waking up 44:E5:17:ED:9E:D2r...
```

And nothing happens. Furhermore, if I follow the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wake-on-LAN), I don't get wake-on-wlan:

```
[root@Arch alex]# ethtool wlo1
Settings for wlo1:
        Link detected: yes
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: I had to use `wakeonlan` with the `-i=<ip>` option (with ip of course replaced with the ip of the system).

Comment: Do you mean instead of using ` wol 44:E5:17:ED:9E:D2r`?

Comment: @shellter Is `wol` the same program as `wakeonlan`? If so, then yes, it worked with me with `wakeonlan -i=<ip> <mac>`, where `<ip>` is the ip of the wlan-interface in the local network and `mac` is the mac address of the wlan-interface.